# Detect DesignTime in WP7 code

Tags: windows-phone-7, design-time

simple question, does anyone know how to detect whether code is executed design-time with WP7? The usual Silverlight solution of HtmlPage.IsEnabled doesn't work in this context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool boolean property.

You will need to import the System.ComponentModel namespace to use this.